# Problem with Ruby OmniComplete in Vim 7.3 finding matches at one line but not 2 lines down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, omnicomplete

Im trying to figure out why ruby omnicompl only works sometimes for me.

[image: Omnicomplete working]
Here it's working as expected.

[image: Trying to same operation on the same ivar 2 lines down]
But when I try the same thing on the same ivar 2 lines down I get "Pattern not found"

Both are done the same way, typing out @current_user_session.fi<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

I checked tpopes rails.vim github page for open/closed issues and tried to google it without luck.

My macvim and vim is compiled with +ruby

`:echo &omnifunc` returns `rubycomplete#Complete`

`:Rails!` returns `rails.vim 4.3 (Rails-controller)`

I have [my complete vimdir on github](https://github.com/pbjorklund/vim-dir) for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one would imagine that it's because in img2 it's now below the setting of the variable (@current_user_session = UserSession.find).

which means that as this is now an instance it's looking for instance methods, whereas before it was returning the class method.

e.g.

```
User.find # => fine


user = User.find
user.find # => Method not found
```

to demo the difference run these:

```
User.methods.sort
User.find.methods.sort
```

you'll see that it's quite different. put bluntly you're trying to look up 'find' for a user you have. "'tom'.find" doesn't make any sense.